# A better way of creating a ruby hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I want to build a hash from an array of rows from a DB. I can easily do it with the code below. I've come to Ruby from PHP and this is how I would do it. Is there a better/proper way to do this in Ruby (or Rails)?

```
def features_hash
  features_hash = {}
  product_features.each do |feature|
    features_hash[feature.feature_id] = feature.value
  end

  features_hash
end

# {1 => 'Blue', 2 => 'Medium', 3 => 'Metal'}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Hash[]`:

```
Hash[ product_features.map{|f| [f.feature_id, f.value]}  ]
```

Would you like this better?

```
product_features.map{|f| [f.feature_id, f.value]}.to_h # no available (yet?)
```

Then go and check out [this feature request](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7292) and comment on it!

Alternative solutions:

```
product_features.each_with_object({}){|f, h| h[f.feature_id] = f.value}
```

There is also `group_by` and `index_by` which could be helpful, but the values will be the features themselves, not their `value`.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks man! RubyMine doesn't like that syntax but it works fine! And yes that method does look handy!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `index_by` for this:

```
product_features.index_by(&:id)
```

This produces the same results as hand-constructing a hash with `id` as the key and the records as the values.

Comment: (I like this solution the best, although it's not what's asked for.)

Comment: I misread the question regarding mapping to `value`.  It is a handy generic way to get things in hash format.  I'll see if I can come up with a shortcut to extract a single value using this.

Comment: I really like this approach, and I could actually make use of it as is, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a good way to do it.  Another way is:

```
def features_hash
  product_features.inject({}) do |features_hash, feature|
    features_hash[feature.feature_id] = feature.value
    features_hash
  end
end
```